# Android 10 scoped storage how to delete the underlying image file in a shared directory

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore, scoped-storage, saf

I'm using scoped storage and `MediaStore` content provider like the in the [documents](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media).

The problem is that the underlying files are not being deleted. (I have yet to see a question specifically on this topic, but many comments are showing this is not unique to me.)

It actually gets worse because when I open the Google Photos app the underlying file is gone only for a split second and gets restored. A new entry for that underlying file is also made in the database.

I confirmed this by using the content provider queries with the old `_id` values and getting empty results. Also, a new entry for the same image is created with a new `_id` field. In the File app, the file is there.

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Should I need to delete the file using SAF?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an old bug, and there doesn't seem to be a way around it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142270549
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145348304